# Something it is wrong in implementation of Strategy Pattern in c#

Tags: c#, strategy-pattern

I am trying implement a Strategy pattern with nested classes.

```
public class Restriction
{
    protected SpecificRestriction _specificRestriction;

    public void SetGreaterRestriction(decimal value)
    {
        Greater greaterRestriction = new Greater();
        greaterRestriction.GreaterValue = value;
        _specificRestriction = greaterRestriction;
    }

    public void SetLessRestriction(decimal value)
    {
        Less lessRestriction = new Less();
        lessRestriction.LessValue = value;
        _specificRestriction = lessRestriction;
    }

    public void SetRangeRestriction(decimal lessValue, decimal greaterValue)
    {
        Range r = new Range();
        r.GreaterValue= greaterValue;
        r.LessValue= lessValue;
        _specificRestriction = r;
    }

    public bool Eval(decimal Value2)
    { 
        return _specificRestriction.Eval(Value2);
    }


    /* Nested strategies classes */

    protected abstract class SpecificRestriction
    {     
        public abstract bool Eval(decimal Value);
    }

    protected class Less : SpecificRestriction
    {
        public decimal LessValue { get; set; }
        public override bool Eval(decimal lessValue)
        {
            return lessValue < LessValue ;
        }
    }

    protected class Greater : SpecificRestriction
    {
        public decimal GreaterValue { get; set; }
        public override bool Eval(decimal greaterValue)
        {
            return greaterValue > GreaterValue;
        }
    }

    protected class Range : SpecificRestriction
    {
        public decimal LessValue { get; set; }
        public decimal GreaterValue { get; set; }

        public override bool Eval(decimal mediumValue)
        {
            return LessValue <= mediumValue && mediumValue <= GreaterValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
        Restriction r = new Restriction();

        r.SetLessRestriction(12);
        r.Eval(13)  // Return false   <- Works!
        r.Eval(11)  // Return True    <- Works!


        r.SetGreaterRestriction(12);
        r.Eval(13)     // Return True    <- Works!
        r.Eval(11)     // Return False   <- Works!

        r.SetRangeRestriction(12, 15);
        r.Eval(13)  // Return false     <- It does not works
        r.Eval(11)  // Return false     <- Works!
        r.Eval(16)  // Return false     <- Works!
```

Why Range it does not works? Am I doing something wrong in Range class?

Comment: Looks to me that r.Eval(13) should return true. You should really refactor this into a Unit Test. You basically already have a unit test here. Are you saying that it IS returning false, or SHOULD return false?

Comment: It does not works due to should return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some change required in Restriction Class and it works

> public class Restriction
>       {
>           protected SpecificRestriction _specificRestriction;
>
> ```
>     public void SetGreaterRestriction(decimal value)
>     {
>         Greater greaterRestriction = new Greater();
>         greaterRestriction.GreaterValue = value;
>         _specificRestriction = greaterRestriction;
>     }
>
>     public void SetLessRestriction(decimal value)
>     {
>         Less lessRestriction = new Less();
>         lessRestriction.LessValue = value;
>         _specificRestriction = lessRestriction;
>     }
>
>     public void SetRangeRestriction(decimal lessValue, decimal greaterValue)
>     {
>         Range r = new Range();
>         r.GreaterValue = greaterValue;
>         r.LessValue = lessValue;
>         _specificRestriction = r;
>     }
>
>     public bool Eval(decimal Value2)
>     {
>         return _specificRestriction.Eval(Value2);
>     }
>
>
>     /* Nested strategies classes */
>
>     protected abstract class SpecificRestriction
>     {
>         public abstract bool Eval(decimal Value);
>     }
>
>     protected class Less : SpecificRestriction
>     {
>         public decimal LessValue { get; set; }
>         public override bool Eval(decimal lessValue)
>         {
>             return lessValue < LessValue;
>         }
>     }
>
>     protected class Greater : SpecificRestriction
>     {
>         public decimal GreaterValue { get; set; }
>         public override bool Eval(decimal greaterValue)
>         {
>             return greaterValue > GreaterValue;
>         }
>     }
>
>     protected class Range : SpecificRestriction
>     {
>         public decimal LessValue { get; set; }
>         public decimal GreaterValue { get; set; }
>
>         public override bool Eval(decimal mediumValue)
>         {
>             return LessValue <= mediumValue && mediumValue <= GreaterValue;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Your Range class doesn't override Eval method, it overrides Evaluar method.

Comment: -1 I am pretty sure that ISN'T the only spelling mistake in the translation. It is obvious that it was translated from another language, and would not compile if that was the issue... Notice _restriccionEspecifica vs _specificRestriction

Comment: @Aron, I don't think this answer deserves -1 (probably can be considered comment), but really it is hard to distinguish spelling mistakes from actual issues. The sample as it is can't compile - so it there is an option it was cut from large framework where there *is* `Evaluar` method and this may explain strange behavior of code.